# Rings with epimorphism from a finitely generated ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

For a commutative ring with unit $R$ let's say it has property $(*)$ if there is an epimorphism in the category of rings ${\mathbb Z}[X_1,\dots,X_n]\to R$, where the former is the polynomial ring in $n$ variables. For instance, finitely generated rings and their localisations have this property.
As an example consider $\mathbb Q$, for which the map ${\mathbb Z}\to\mathbb Q$ is an epimorphism.

Does this property have a name? How is it related to other properties of a ring?

Comment: It's called "quotients of $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,\dots,X_n]$"...

Comment: @Tom_de_Medts: Sorry no, that would mean that the map is surjective, which it isn't in general. You wouldn't call the field $\mathbb Q$ of rationals a quotient of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Wait, didn't you write "ring epimorphism"? (Perhaps you meant "epic morphism" then, which isn't the same!)

Comment: @Tom_de_Medts: The term epimorphism is defined in any catgegory and a ring epimorphism is an epimorphism in the category of rings. Otherwise I would have written surjective ring homomorphism.

Comment: I've seen the term finitely dominated used in semigroup theory which is another category where epimorphism is not the same as surjective. The origin comes from Isbell's notion of dominion.  If R' is a subring of R, the dominion of R' is the subring of R consisting of all elements of R equalized by all homomorphisms from R that agree on R'.  The inclusion is an epimorphism iff the dominion of R' is R. So the idea is being finitely dominated means you are the dominion of a finitely generated subring. This is the same as having an epimorphism from a finitely generated free object.

Comment: @Echo Sure, now that you have rephrased it as "epimorphism in the category of rings" and added the example, I of course agree. (From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimorphism#Terminology: "Saunders Mac Lane attempted to create a distinction between epimorphisms, which were maps in a concrete category whose underlying set maps were surjective, and epic morphisms, which are epimorphisms in the modern sense. However, this distinction never caught on.")

Comment: @Benjamin_Steinberg: Thanks, that's helpful.